# Correctly read gzip file

Tags: java, byte, gzip

```
public static byte[] decompressGzipToBytes(String file) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    try (GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(in)) {

        // copy GZIPInputStream to ByteArrayOutputStream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, len);
            System.out.println(buffer);
        }

    }

    return output.toByteArray();

}
```

The above code doesn't properly read a Gzip file into bytes.  I get characters like '[B@6d6f6e28' instead.  But, if I use a BufferReader for text files, then it behaves as expected.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try like below if that works

```
GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzip));
br.readLine();
```

Comment: The BufferReader works for me, but I was looking to get bytes output working.